# ASP.NET Core getting data list via ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Edit: Ok Ive just noticed this. each time I try to add the ID of the user inside the table it always adds a new ID. maybe that is the reason I am getting 0 in count.

I am trying to get all the data from a table with `userID` in it. Example users favorite movies.

I retrieve the ID from my database and trying to do the following.

What am I doing wrong? There are items in the table `Favourites` with the ID of that user. but I still get count 0.

```
 var  item = _db.Favorites.Where(s => s.Userid.Equals(userId)).ToList();        

 // Here the (userID) has userID in it, but var item has count 0 in it. 
 // So I can never access my foreach loop 
 foreach (var movie in item)
 {
     ....
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If UserId is Integer**

```
if(userId != null && userId > 0)
 {
   var  item = _db.Favorites.Where(s => s.Userid == userId).ToList();
 }
```

**If UserId is String**

```
if(userId != null)
  {
    var  item = _db.Favorites.Where(s => s.Userid.ToLower() == userId.ToLower()).ToList();
  }
```

OR

```
if(userId != null)
      {
        var  item = _db.Favorites.Where(s => String.Equals(s.Userid.ToLower() ,userId.ToLower()).ToList();
      }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply I appreciate your time , but I have found a new issue I need to resolve before I get back to this. the controller returns to me  an encrypted userID> so each time i save it its a new one.

Comment: Hello again. 
the logic for this is correct. but whats going on in my database base is not.. My user ID is something like this 634c817e-533e-471b-9aab-b3a5b7b204b9 . but when I save it in the database it saves something completely different

Comment: Are you doing some kind of `encrypting`  before saving it ?

Comment: no, I was not saving the data correctly, I was using a wrong method to pull the userid from UserIdentity thats why this was happening. my initial loop was correct. but the ones you shared are working as well So I will be accepting your answer